# How to modelize items in a shop (like LoL, Dota, ...) the MVC way?

Tags: design, object-oriented-design, mvc, game-development

In a 2D game, *buildings* can be upgraded with *modules*; Those *modules* can be bought in a *shop*.

The *shop* is represented by a stereotyped grid of icons, each icon representing a buyable *module*. When the mouse hovers an icon, the name a description of the associated *module* appear in a popup.

Currently, the *modules* are model objects extending an abstract `Module` class wearing the following data:

- The name of the *module*
- A description of what it does to your *building*
- The icon used to display the *module* in the *shop*'s grid
- Also, some `f(building)`-like methods to actually "modulize" the *building*...

At the beginning of the game, the *shop* is provided with a list of *modules*. When applying a *module* to a *building* the `f(building)` methods are called on the bought *module*. Thus, even not using the Singleton pattern, each `*Module` class is instantiated only once.

I'm conscious that this design is not really optimal:

- First, a *module*, a **model** object, embeds its own icon, a **view** representation.
- And more important: a *module* is stateless because the same object can be applied on several *buildings* (possibly of different players); in order to be stateful, a *module* would have to wear a `[building] => data` map... I don't know why, but I have a bad feeling about this solution...

Question time:

- Is the `[building] => data` map **effectively** a bad solution?
- If so, what's the best way to solve the "statefulness" pitfall I'm encountering?
- Subsidiary one: also, it would be more MVC-compliant if each model object didn't have to wear an image...

Comment: Feel free to correct any language mistake of mine. BTW, it's my first post here, so I'm not sure of the tags I used; feel free to change them as well.

Comment: If I buy an upgrade to a building, can I choose which of my possibly several buildings to apply it to? Can I choose in which order to apply multiple upgrades or does that not make any sense? Can I buy an upgrade multiple times?

Comment: Yes: you can choose which _building_ (one at a time) you want to upgrade. -- The effects of a newly applied _module_ are stacked on top of the effects already set up by other _modules_; there's an order, but you don't chose it... -- There's no limit on the number of _modules_ you can apply to a _building_ (maybe in the future), and you can stack the same _module_ on one _building_ several times.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

First, you have `IModuleDefinition` interface. Primary purpose of this interface is to identify a module, possibly through having some unique identifier for a module. It will have methods like `CreateView` and `CreateModule`. Those will create concrete instances that will be used to display the module information (`IModuleView`) and implement the module behavior (`IModule`). This also means any number of instances can be created for each type of module, so state can be inside the module instance.

Comment: If I understand well, the `IModuleDefinition` is a `IModuleView` - `IModule` couple... Where would all these classes and interfaces be located (namespacingly speaking)?

Comment: @Odepax No definition is not a view/module. It creates them. And namespace-wise, they would all be in same place. I can even imagine `ConcreteModuleDefinition` class with `ConcreteModuleView` and `ConcreteModule` being private classes of it.

Comment: So they are in the same namespace, but is this one of the MVC namespaces or a new one? How do I extend `ConcreteModuleView` and `ConcreteModule` if they are private?

Comment: Wait a minute... What's the purpose of separating the view and the behavior if "they would all be in same place" eventually? BTW: in your design, is an `IModuleView` implementation just an object that wears an image or a URI to it, or barely a custom UI control?